# Docker e Intellij IDe

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, ide, deployment

mi problemas es necesito hacer el `deployment`  de una app Java , posea mi `DockerFile` bien , pero el problema es que cuando estoy creando la configuración del run docker en la ventana de asistencia solo en la sección de deployment solo aparace una opcion que trae por defeco que es docker image y no me aparece mi `dockerfile` ni  me da alguna opcion para seleccionarlo . la version de mi intellij es

> community edition 2017.2 EAP
>   [image: Vean que deployment sale solo docker image como se muestra]

y También cada vez que hago un cambio para poderlo ver tengo que borrar todos los container y las imágenes, y volver a crear las imágenes de docker y tengo que esperar que se descargue todo nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

En la opción de `deployment` de `Intellij` te pide que seleciones la imagen que quieres "desplegar", esa imagen es la que construyes con tu software, por ejemplo cuando haces:

```
docker build -t  name_image:tag  path_dockerfile
```

Selecionala y busca el path de tu `Dockerfile` y si te pide la imagen, intenta pasarla de acuerdo al nombre que te entrega el comando.

`docker images`

Revisa también que `Intellij` contenga el plugin de `docker integration`, puedes seguir el siguiente tutorial para realizar `run/debug` de `Docker images` [Run/Debug Configuration: Docker Deployment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-docker-deployment.html). Respecto a la necesidad de eliminar las imagenes y contenedores, recuerda que si realizas un cambio en la imagen debes construir la imagen con:

`docker build`

Si configuras volumenes compartidos no es necesario realizar la construición, puedes ver los cambios reflejados en tu contenedor. Creo que sería bueno que revises los primeros pasos de `Docker` [Docker getting started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/)

Comment: Amigo encontre otra solucion gracias por su ayuda